# tem como dar include em pasta anterior em c++?

Tags: c++

ex:[image: gerenciadorDeArquivos]

é possível o main.cpp dar include no header.h?

Comment: ???. Você que incluir `header.h` mas você tem como disponível `header1.h`.

Answer (score 2):

Adicionando o valor da diretiva `include` entre aspas, o arquivo será procurado relativo ao diretório atual. Para incluir um header de uma pasta superior/anterior, podes usar dois pontos:

```
#include "../header1.h"
```

Se entendi o seu exemplo:

```
#include "../headers/header1.h"
```

Comment: obrigado, me ajudou com esta duvida

Comment: Que bom :) Se considerar a resposta correta, favor marque como respondida.